# C# Setter and if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, properties, setter

I've been watching a tutorial about OOP in C#.

I don't understand why the  assignment of the value to the name inside of a Name property isn't inside of else-clause.

```
class Animal
{
    private string name;
    protected string sound;

    public Animal()
        :this("No Name", "No Sound") { }

    public Animal(string name)
        :this(name, "No Sound") { }

    public Animal(string name, string sound)
    {
        Name = name;
        Sound = sound;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }

        set
        {
            if (!value.Any(char.IsDigit))
            {
                name = "No Name";
            }
            name = value;


        }
    }

    public string Sound
    {
        get { return sound; }

        set
        {
            if (value.Length > 10)
            {
                sound = "No Sound";
            }
            else
            {
                sound = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected AnimalIDInfo animalIDInfo = new AnimalIDInfo();

    public void SetAnimalIDInfo(int idNum, string owner)
    {
        animalIDInfo.IDNum = idNum;
        animalIDInfo.Owner = owner;
    }

    public void GetAnimalIDInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} has the ID of {animalIDInfo.IDNum} and is owned by {animalIDInfo.Owner}");
    }

    public void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} says {Sound}");
    }


}
```

}

Could someone explain me this, please? Isn't this code going to always assign a value to the name no matter of the if statement?

On the other hand, when I tried with an else clause then I get "No Name" even if the value i'm passing doesn't contain any digits.

Here is the Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal whiskers = new Animal()
        {
            Name = "Whiskers",
            Sound = "Meow"
        };

        Dog grover = new Dog()
        {
            Name = "Grover",
            Sound = "Woof",
            Sound2 = "Grrrr"
        };

        grover.Sound = "Woooooooof";

        whiskers.MakeSound();
        grover.MakeSound();

        // Inheritance has an "is a" relationship ("A dog IS AN animal")

        // aggregation or a delegate represents "has a" relationship

        whiskers.SetAnimalIDInfo(12345, "Sally Smith");
        grover.SetAnimalIDInfo(12346, "Paul Brown");

        whiskers.GetAnimalIDInfo();
        grover.GetAnimalIDInfo();




    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most tutorials are garbage written by amateurs, tech writers, and the like. Yes, that assignment should be in an `else` branch. `if (!value.Any(char.IsDigit))` means "if not any character is a digit", i.e. if no character is a digit. I think the boolean negation `!` doesn't belong there. As it is, it's rejecting any name that has no digits in it.

Comment: Setting something to a nonsense value in a prop setter as part of validation ("No Name") lacks conceptual integrity anyway

Comment: Books > Videos generally

Comment: `name = value.Any(char.IsDigit) ? "No Name" : value;` you could also look into the [StringValidatorAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.stringvalidatorattribute?view=netframework-4.8) class...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ But that's ridiculous anyway. It should throw, or give somebody a meaningful error message, or just accept the fact that Chad Barrington Wellesley 3rd has a digit in his name. "Here's a (broken) wrong way to do something preposterous" is typical tutorial.

Comment: I would agree as well :) either way it's wrong. If I could, my name would be `0110010001101111011011000110110001111001`; I may make a phone call..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not figure it out either. As it is written now, the result of the if will always been overwritten by `name = value;`. Honestly it is likely that the JiT's dead code detection might notice that one and just cut out the if entirely. Unless he is planning to teach you about that one, I seen no point in this code.

Also the return value of `value.Any(char.IsDigit)` is inverted, wich is propably the last thing you should be doing there. Really, unless he was trying to teach you debugging or is live coding, I see no way this could work.

The closest sensible code I can make of it is:

```
if (value.Any(char.IsDigit))
{
  name = "No Name";
}
else{
  name = value;
}
```

Comment: You fixed it I see :), the `!`

Comment: Thank you a lot!
It seems like the author of the tutorial messed some things up! :P

Comment: @Nat13alia is it [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Authors/47446/dany4ev) guy?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ no idea, but this is the video of this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzVxgJmLAsE&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvRX6xK1oi0reKci6ignjdSa&index=7

Comment: Apparently a commenter noted the issue in this setter too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzVxgJmLAsE&lc=Ugzl8HEBcZIZwV4EO5t4AaABAg